# Problem with cmake and package libccext2

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo, compiling, make

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/etherlab ../pdserv-1.1.0
-- Mercurial was not found.
-- checking for module 'libccext2'
--   package 'libccext2' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:116 (PKG_CHECK_MODULES)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/etherlab/src/pdserv-1.1.0-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have already tried

```
sudo apt-get install libccext2
```

but it doesn't work. I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libccext2
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a reference to the (possibly deprecated?) GNU `commoncpp` library - see [\[etherlab-users\] issue with installation PdServ](http://lists.etherlab.org/pipermail/etherlab-users/2014/002628.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is available for all Ubuntu versions http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=commoncpp&searchon=names

```
sudo apt install libcommoncpp2-dev
```

Provides

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccext2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccext2.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccext2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccgnu2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccgnu2.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccgnu2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libccext2.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libccgnu2.pc
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libcommoncpp2-dev/filelist